# PHP Mail Script hitting error

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP mail script set up and keep hitting the error "Something went wrong, go back and try again!" all the form fields have been checked and all the names match etc so I am wondering if there is something wrong with my script?

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="contactForm">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="name" />
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email" />
                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="phone" />
                            <label for="iam">I Am</label>
                            <select name="iam" class="iam" id="iam">
                                <option>a recruiter looking to recruit staff</option>
                                <option>a construction worker looking for work</option>
                                <option>requesting information</option>
                            </select>
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="message"></textarea>

                            <label for="captcha">What is 3+4?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" class="captcha" />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" />
                        </form>




<?php
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$iam    = $_POST['iam'];
$human   = $_POST['captcha'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from    = 'From: Test';
$to      = 'sales@test.com';
$headers = "From: $email";
$subject = 'Tradeline Contact';
$body    = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone Number:\n $phone I Am:\n $iam Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '7') {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from)) {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        header( 'Location: http://urlhere.com/thankyou.html' ) ;
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '7') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"I am wondering if there is something with my script?"* http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: tip: you're outputting before header

Comment: Removed echo before header and I have also updated my question to "I am wondering if there is something wrong with my script?"

Comment: use error reporting as I said above Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Tried with error reporting and I am not receiving an error. I feel the script is relatively OK but it is hitting the if else when it shouldn't as it should be submitting and then relocating to the above header location. Any ideas what could be up?

Comment: looks like mail is returning false, first check it is then debug that

Comment: It's formatted fine - what mail host are you using? Also, you might try it with fewer parameters to see if one of them is causing the issue (ie, without setting the envelope sender (take of the -f portion); without setting $headers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from)
```

to:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers."\r\n")
```

That way your mail headers will be in compliance.

Also, turn on error reporting. I happen to use `error_reporting(7);` right under the `<?php` line to turn on all common errors with the exception of catching undefined variables, and that will tell me if the mail function has problems.

Another thing you can do is check the mail server logs to see if mail is actually being sent.

I'm sure you already did this, but in case you haven't, make sure you use valid email addresses.

Comment: Really appreciate the help and after checking there was no problems with the code at all. It was server related and seemed to be a common problem with the host I use(1and1).